# How to import data from mainframe to cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, sqoop, datastax-enterprise, bigdata

Using dse sqoop can we import data from mainframe databases (DB2,IMS etc) to Datastax Cassandra? If yes, please let me know how.

Thanks.

Comment: Apache Cassandra or DSE ?

Comment: Using DSE is it possible?

Comment: Check this link http://www.datastax.com/2012/03/how-to-move-data-from-relational-databases-to-datastax-enterprise-cassandra-using-sqoop